# How I do sort numbers saved as strings ascending in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have some data in my MySQL database such as:

```
01, 001, 2, 9, 009, 23, 15, 19, 09, 08, 1 etc.
```

So, I want to sort the data ascending like:

```
001, 01, 1, 1, 2, 08, 009, 09, 9, 15, 19, 23 etc.
```

If I use `ORDER BY value ASC`, It doesn't work. How should I be sorting it? I want the first value to be 1, then 2, 3 ..... Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are stored as string, you can simply multiply it by one as mysql automatically parses the value to a number. If it happens that the string starts with a letter, the value will be equal to zero.

```
ORDER BY col * 1, col
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf1662/1)

As you can see, the `order by` clause does not have `ASC` keyword because by default, the optimizer sorts it in ascending order.

Answer (score 3):

What you've written should work with integers. From your question though, I'm assuming that the numbers you're specifying are being stored as strings, so they're being sorted as string.

In that case, you need to cast them to integers for the sorting to work properly. That's as easy as doing something like

```
ORDER BY <column> / 1 ASC, <column>
```

Multiplying or dividing by 1 causes the database to convert the string to an integer before sorting. The second use of  means that `001` will always come before `1`.

Re-reading your question, it sounds like you only are expecting to see `1` once, even if the table includes both `1` and `001`. In that case do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (<column> / 1) AS intcol
FROM ...
ORDER BY intcol
```

Comment: Its string value. If I use letter, then it's possible?

Comment: You are not multiplying here, just sayin' ;)

Comment: Thanks for the spot. Saw the other answer, just as I was finishing my own, got confused. Cheers. Dreamless, if you cast to integers before the main bit of sorting, it'll work how you're expecting. The easiest way to do that is as in @491243's answer, or my own.